# Is there a app similar to CrystalDiskInfo (used in desktop machine) for android phone

Tags: android

CrystalDiskInfo is a HDD health monitoring utility. It displays basic HDD information, monitors S.M.A.R.T. values and disk temperature.

So, is there an android app that is similar to CrystalDiskInfo, that can monitor the phone storage and additional storage devices (such as micro-SD card) that is insert into the phone?

Comment: What features do you expect from this application? If you want just the usage information, you can use ES explorer. As for disk temperatures etc, I am not sure. CPU-Z displays information from all the sensors. This includes accelerometres, gyroscopes and temperature sensors.

Comment: You do not have a HDD on your phone. you have an SD card that doesn't get hot by its own. Hence you don't have a sensor for that. Neither SMART values. You can only run a checkdisk kind of an application once in a while, but SD devices do not have such a health monitoring reporting software integrated.

Comment: también busco ese tipo de aplicación para poder testear un disco duro en campo sin necesidad de un ordenador portátil